# jinja2 Template .generate() vs .render() methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Considering the following implementation using `Template.generate()` method:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template_data = '''\
{%- for variable in range(1, 3) -%}
foo{{ variable }}bar
{% endfor %}
'''

template = Template(template_data)
for rendered in template.generate():
    print(rendered)
```

Output:

```
foo
1
bar

foo
2
bar
```

Note that the behaviour of `Template.generate()` method **is not the same** as `Template.render()`:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template_data = '''\
{%- for variable in range(1, 3) -%}
foo{{ variable }}bar
{% endfor %}
'''

template = Template(template_data)
rendered = template.render()
print(rendered)
```

Output:

```
foo1bar
foo2bar
```

Why `Template.generate()` method is adding a `newline` **before** and **after** jinja2's print statements? Could this behaviour be configured though `Enviroment` options? Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is different is the way you print. (at once vs. in parts)